# Better way to run bash code inside python script when iterating

Tags: python, bash, list, subprocess

I have a bash code that when run in the terminal with an item key next to it, spits out the number associated with the item. For example:

```
./bashcode 1912 W
```

gives:

```
549002
```

However, I have about 250,000 objects (the keys are stored in a list called `desiglist`) that I need to run this code on. I then need to store all of these output numbers into a list. I need to do it in a python script, so I came up with this:

```
import subprocess
nums = [None]*len(desiglist)
for i in range(len(desiglist)):
    nums[i] = subprocess.check_output(["./bashcode", desiglist[i]])
print nums
```

However, this takes way too long to run considering how many items I'm iterating over. Is there a way to get my desired result in a reasonable amount of time?

Comment: Starting up a new subprocess 250,000 times is **always** going to be slow. The way to make it not slow is to not do it.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't write your bash script to take more than one input per invocation? Or port the logic it contains over to Python? (Actually, if you really care about performance, even Python isn't necessarily ideal -- I'd reach first for [Go](https://golang.org/) or [Julia](https://julialang.org/)).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Is there a way to do it other than subprocess? And it's because it's someone else's old code that I have to work with, but I don't have access to its actual contents

Comment: Your bottleneck isn't the `subprocess` module, it's the work `subprocess` is doing under the hood to actually fork off a new OS-level process and execute a new shell interpreter in it. You'll have that same work no matter what you do in your Python, if you continue to run a shell interpreter for each item.

Comment: (You might be able to squeeze out some performance by parallelizing -- running, say, two processes at a time for each CPU in your system -- but it'll still be slow).

Comment: I see; maybe there's a way to get my desired outcome without iterating over each item? Although I can't think of a different method besides the loop

Comment: (If the bash isn't well-written, it's probably wasting a whole lot of time/resources there too; naively-written shell scripts can be *extremely* inefficient, and people who know how to write them well are rare).

Comment: You'd really want to edit the bash script to have a better calling convention, or just reimplement it natively. If you could run `./bashcode 1912 W 1325 N 1420 O ...`, then you can use a much smaller number of invocations, so you're amortizing the overhead. Need to distinguish the outputs, but that's not so hard -- just need a good delimiter syntax. But if it's someone else's script you can't edit, you're in a tough spot.

Comment: ("smaller number of invocations", not just one invocation, because there's an OS-level limit on combined size of the command line and the set of defined environment variables you can't go over; a way to avoid that is to pass input on stdin rather than on the command line).

Comment: Unfortunately the code only gives me the correct output for one item at a time. In this case I'm guessing I'll probably just have to use the iteration method and deal with the slowness?

Comment: If you can't fix or reimplement the bash script, then yes, you're stuck dealing with it.

Comment: BTW, re: "don't have access to its actual contents" -- if you can run it, then you can see what it does when it's run. Scripts can't really be obfuscated (unless it's actually a shim that performs privilege escalation to switch to a different user who can read the source code when your own user account can't, or such) -- if you run `bash -x ./bashcode 1912 W`, it'll print to stderr every line it runs (which is likely to be useful for figuring out what it's doing and how to do that in your own code, faster).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155040/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-wynne-t).